# Why can't I cancel my executor submited job?

Tags: java, multithreading, future, java-threads, executor

I'm unsuccessfully trying to cancel a thread submitted with this code

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<Object> future = executor.submit(()-> {while(true) { System.out.println("Thread"); Thread.yield();} } );
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  future.cancel(true);
  executor.shutdown();
```

but the thread stays running.
When sleep is used instead of yield, the thread does get cancelled. For example this does cancel the thread:

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<Object> future = executor.submit(()-> {while(true) { System.out.println("Thread"); Thread.sleep(1000);} } );
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  future.cancel(true);
  executor.shutdown();
```

What's going on? Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: Yes, the fact that you are running a tight loop and that threads in Java are basically not killable, only interruptible. `Thread.yield()` does nothing, really. Your thread should check for the interrupt bit or perform interruptible operations. I'd recommend reading a good tutorial on threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first task is NOT responsive to interruption. But the second task is responsive because `Thread.sleep` is a blocking method which is responsive to interruption. One way to solve the issue is by making your task responsive to interruption. Here's how it looks.

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(() -> {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        System.out.println("Thread");
});
```

Moreover `Thread.yield` is just a scheduler hint to yield its current use of a processor. This operation is platform dependent and should not be used in practice. Hence I have removed it from my answer.

Comment: I think the appropriate method to use would be `Thread.interrupted()` rather than `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` which should be used for threads other than the current.

Comment: Interesting, but that clears the interrupted status of that thread, so I am a bit reluctant to use that.

Comment: Since you are executing a task inside a thread pool (you are not the owner of the Thread so you do not know what interruption means to it) the interruption status should be preserved.

Comment: @michalk you are right to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to stop all submitted tasks you could use

```
executor.shutdownNow();
```

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of
>   waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting
>   execution.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()

---

As already mentioned in the comments section of the question, it is the difference between `.sleep(1000)` and `.yield()` behaviour for interrupt calls

Comment: I don't see how using `shutdownNow()` would be better than `cancel` - it does the same - tries to interrupt the thread. If the thread is not interruptible, it will continue running.

Comment: Future.cancel is the easiest way to interrupt a thread. I don't see any point of using shutdownNow here. Just a graceful shutdown would be suffice. The thread has already been interrupted, hence `sutdownNow` has no use here.